# Rails 4 - Pundit - policies not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit, policies

I'm trying to figure out how to use Pundit in my Rails 4 app.

I have a project model, with a projects controller that has a new action in it:

```
def new
# a bunch of stuff in the new action that I don't think is very relevant here

end
```

I then have a project policy in my policies folder that has:

```
def new?
        false
        # create?
    end

    def create?
        false

    end
```

I expect that I should not be able to type url/projects/new in my website because the policy shouldn't allow it. But, I can, and the form renders and I can save it.

Does anyone see what I've done wrong in setting this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to check because you didn't mention them in your question:

1. Add `include Pundit` to the controller
2. Add `authorize [model_instance]` in `new` action and `create` action

The official https://github.com/elabs/pundit should give you plenty of instruction.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt americanise the spelling of authorise.